# Select com subquery para pegar registro anterior

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, desempenho

Tenho uma estrutura de registros de leituras do usuário por referência.
Conforme dados abaixo.

```sql
SELECT L.LeituraID, L.UsuarioID, L.Referencia, L.Leitura
FROM Leituras AS L
```

```
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------|
| LeituraID | UsuarioID | Referencia | Leitura |
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------|
| 1         | 1         | 01/01/2018 | 52      |
| 2         | 2         | 01/01/2018 | 157     |
| 3         | 3         | 01/01/2018 | 73      |
| 4         | 1         | 01/02/2018 | 63      |
| 5         | 2         | 01/02/2018 | 171     |
| 6         | 3         | 01/02/2018 | 89      |
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------|
```

Preciso pegar os dados da leitura do usuário por uma data de referência e fazer um calculo do consumo.

Para efetuar o calculo do consumo é preciso ter a informação da leitura anterior.

Montei a query trazendo os dados da leitura atual e uma subquery para pegar a leitura anterior.

O problema é que essa busca com a subquery esta demorando demais.

Existe alguma forma de obter essa leitura anterior de uma forma mais rápida?

```sql
WITH cteLeituras AS (
    SELECT 
        L.LeituraID
        , L.UsuarioID
        , L.Referencia
        , L.Leitura
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 LA.Leitura 
            From Leituras AS LA 
            WHERE LA.UsuarioID = L.UsuarioID AND LA.Referencia < L.Referencia
            ORDER BY LA.Referencia DESC
        ) AS LeituraAnterior
    FROM Leituras AS L
    WHERE L.Referencia = '2018-02-01'
), cteLeiturasConsumo AS (
    SELECT 
        L.LeituraID
        , L.UsuarioID
        , L.Referencia
        , L.Leitura
        , L.LeituraAnterior
        , (L.Leitura - L.LeituraAnterior) AS Consumo
    FROM cteLeituras AS L 
)
```

```
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------|-----------------|---------|
| LeituraID | UsuarioID | Referencia | Leitura | LeituraAnterior | Consumo |
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------|-----------------|---------|
| 4         | 1         | 01/02/2018 | 63      | 52              | 11      |
| 5         | 2         | 01/02/2018 | 171     | 157             | 14      |
| 6         | 3         | 01/02/2018 | 89      | 73              | 16      |
|-----------|-----------|------------|---------|-----------------|---------|
```

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: @JoséDiz é a versão 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx) particionada por `usuarioid` para conseguir a ordem das leituras e realizar o cálculo:

```
WITH ordenado AS (
  SELECT l.leituraid,
      l.usuarioid,
      l.referencia,
      l.leitura,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.usuarioid ORDER BY l.referencia) AS ordem
  FROM leituras l
)
SELECT atual.*,
      (atual.leitura - ISNULL(anterior.leitura, 0)) AS consumo
  FROM ordenado atual
      LEFT JOIN ordernado anterior ON anterior.usuarioid = atual.usuarioid
                                  AND anterior.ordem = atual.ordem - 1
WHERE atual.referencia = '2018-02-01'
```

> [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

Comment: Interessante, obrigado pela resposta.
Fiz uns testes e dependendo do filtro utilizado acaba demorando mais que a subquery.
Filtrando por 1 unico usuário ficou extremamente rápido, mas por referencia ficou mais lento.

Comment: Percebi que se eu coloco o filtro direto no with ae fica perfeito. porem preciso que seja executado em uma view aonde posso passar o filtro que eu quiser.

Comment: @DaniloRibeirodaSilveira em uma `view` você vai realmente precisar fazer para todos os registros. O que você pode fazer é criar um índice por `usuarioid` e `referencia` na tabela, isso deve agilizar bastante a consulta

Answer (score -2):

Se usa firebird 3.0 ou superior pode utilizar o comando LAG, mais ou menos assim:

```
    SELECT l.leituraid,
       l.usuarioid,
       l.referencia,
       l.leitura,
       LAG(l.leitura) OVER(ORDER BY l.leituraid) AS leitura_anterior
  FROM leituras AS l
ORDER BY l.leituraid
```

Comment: Lembrado que tem esta possibilidade (lag lead) no SqlServer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16